# 2 by 2 matrices with a fixed determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

Fix a complex number $z$ with modulus at most one. What are all examples of **non-triangular** $2\times 2$ matrices with $z$ as its determinant? The question has satisfactory answer in the triangular matrix situation because of two reasons: (1) every matrix can be (say) upper triangularized and (2) for the triangular matrices, the question boils down to finding all possible factorizations $z=\lambda_1\cdot\lambda_2$ and then the matrices of the following form are all:
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & *\\
0 & \lambda_2
\end{bmatrix}
This is why I am interested in the non-triangular case. Therefore I am interested in knowing **all possible** matrices of the form
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & x_2\\
x_3 & x_4
\end{bmatrix} such that none of $x_2,x_3$ is zero and that $x_1x_4-x_2x_3=z.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_3 \neq 0$, then we can solve for $x_2$ as follows:
$$
x_1x_4 - x_2x_3 = z \implies x_2 = \frac{x_1x_4 - z}{x_3}
$$
If you like, we could parameterize the set of matrices for which $x_2,x_3$ are non-zero as follows:
$$
M = \pmatrix{a& \frac{ac - z}{b}\\b&c} \quad a,b,c \in \Bbb C, \quad b \neq 0, \quad ac \neq z
$$